# Tizen install failed: Security Error [-22]

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

When installing an .NET application that was build with the tizen cli using: tizen build-cs -s Samsung-Certificate

I get the following error as seen in the attachment:  Security Error [-22].

Is there any fix for this?
[image: cmd log]

Comment: Hello, would you let us know which target was used for test? mobile/wearable/tv, emulator/real device, tizen version, etc...

Comment: Hi thank you for commenting. I already solved this issue. My issue originated because I was packaging the aplication. I just skipped packaging and now it installs